# Use numerical methods to find the value of 6 variables using 5 equations

Tags: python, methods, permutation, numeric

There is one combination of b1, b2, b3, r1, r2, r3 which meets the following equations:

```
b1 = 4 * r1
b2 = 4 * r2
b3 = 4 * r3
b1 = b2 + b3
r1 = r2 + r3
```

I have been trying to write a piece of python code to find that combination (or maybe there is more than one). The piece of code has to go through various permutations to find the right combination. I was struggling to write the code so hopefully someone can help me out. This is what i started off with:

```
for b1 in range(9,50):
    for b2 in range(9,50):
        for b3 in range(5,20):
            for r1 in range(5,20):
                for r2 in range(5,20):
                    for r3 in range(5,20):
                        if b1 == 4 * r1 & b2 == 4 * r2 & b3 == 4 * r3 & b1 == b2 + b3 & r1 == r2 + r3:
                            print(b1, b2, b3, r1, r2, r3)
```

Comment: There is more than one combination that satisfies your equations, unless there are some constraints for the values that you haven't included (min/max)

Comment: In fact, if you have 6 unknowns and only 5 equations there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: find the r1 r2 r3 that fits ```r1 = r2 + r3``` then check if b1 b2 b3 are within range

Comment: there are in fact only 4 equations in this case. I'm assuming there's a range restriction on the variables

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've completely missed what the desired outcome is supposed to be from the equations above, there are countless permutations that produce a true comparison of values for "r1", "r2", "r3", "b1", "b2", and "b3".  That is because the equation:

```
b1 = b2 + b3
```

is equivalent to:

```
4 * r1 = 4 * (r2 + r3)
```

So once you determine what value of "r1" is equal to "r2 + r3", the "b1" equation is going to follow suit.

I built the following proof of principle program to test that out using just eighty-one combinations of values for "r2" and "r3" and solving for "r1" with a check of "b1".

```
r1 = 0
r2 = 0
r3 = 0

b1 = 0
b2 = 0
b3 = 0

print("Valid combinations of r1/r2/r3")
print("______________________________________________________________")

for r2 in range (1, 10):
    for r3 in range (1, 10):
        r1 = r2 + r3
        b1 = 4 * r1
        b2 = 4 * r2
        b3 = 4 * r3
        if (b1 == (4 * (r2 + r3))):
            print("r1:", r1, "r2:", r2, "r3:", r3)
            print("r1 = r2 + r3, which is", r1, "=", r2, "+", r3)
            print("b1 =", b1, "b2 =", b2, "b3 =", b3)
            print("b1 = b2 + b3, which is", b1, "=", b2, "+", b3)
            print("- - - - - - - - - - - - -")
```

That yielded eighty-one instances where all of the parameters are met.

```
r1: 17 r2: 9 r3: 8
r1 = r2 + r3, which is 17 = 9 + 8
b1 = 68 b2 = 36 b3 = 32
b1 = b2 + b3, which is 68 = 36 + 32
- - - - - - - - - - - - -
r1: 18 r2: 9 r3: 9
r1 = r2 + r3, which is 18 = 9 + 9
b1 = 72 b2 = 36 b3 = 36
b1 = b2 + b3, which is 72 = 36 + 36
- - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

The exercise almost seems more of a proof that if the first four equations are true, the fifth equation is true.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thank you for your time. I just realized I needed a different set of equations. The problem is about blue and red tiles. A child has a huge amount of blue tiles and red tiles, the number is unknown. He uses all the blue tiles to form a rectangle and the red tiles to form a border around the rectangle of 1 tile thickness, he has 4 times as many blues tiles as red tiles. He then messes us the rectangle and forms 2 smaller (unidentical) rectangles using all of the tiles. Each rectangle follows the same convention of blue rectangle and red border consisting of 1 tile thickness. The question asks to find the number of blue and red tiles for each rectangle (big/medium/small). Algebraically I only see 5 equations which can be formed but 6 unknowns so I have no idea how to solve it algebraically but I realized I can use brute force to get the answer using python. In the end, I slept on it for a few days and tried again just now and got the answer.
This was a question my 14yr cousin got as his math homework, haha. I still couldn't work it out algebraically, I guess his teacher will find the solution. Thank you again for your time and apologies I only later realized the equations needed to be amended.
The below solves the answer.

```
for w1 in range(10, 100):
    for w2 in range(10, 50):
        for w3 in range(10, 25):
            for l1 in range(5, 15):
                for l2 in range(5, 15):
                    for l3 in range(5, 15):
                        if (w1 * l1 == (w2 * l2) + (w3 * l3)) and \
                        (((w1 * l1) / 4) == ((w2 * l2) / 4) + ((w3 * l3) / 4)) and \
                        (w1 * l1 == (8 * w1) + (8 * l1) + 16) and \
                        (w2 * l2 == (8 * w2) + (8 * l2) + 16) and \
                        (w3 * l3 == (8 * w3) + (8 * l3) + 16):
                            print("blue tiles for big rectangle is", int(w1 * l1))
                            print("red tiles for big rectangle is", int((w1 * l1) /4))
                            print("blue tiles for medium rectangle is", int(w2 * l2))
                            print("red tiles for medium rectangle is", int((w2 * l2) /4))
                            print("blue tiles for small rectangle is", int(w3 * l3))
                            print("red tiles for small rectangle is", int((w3 * l3) /4))
                        else:
                            None
```